# Angular 4 component and css flex order

Tags: angular, css, flexbox

I have a plunker here - https://plnkr.co/edit/rnN8oQAsIcYWjsjQHfuk?p=preview

It's a simple nav style set up using `display: flex;` and `order` to position the elements

The elements use flex order to order them 1, 2, 3, 4

This is basic but the actual code needs the order.

The top nav is just four div's in the html and they are ordered 1, 2, 3, 4

The bottom nav is the same as the top but the 'Three' element is added as an component.

The html and class in the 'Three' component is the same as the 'Three' in the top nav.

The flex order doesn't seem to work on the Angular component.

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work and how to fix it.

```
<div class="nav-container">

  <div class="nav">

    <div class="nav-item nav-item-one">
      One
    </div>

    <div class="nav-item  nav-item-two">
      Two
    </div>

    <div class="nav-item  nav-item-three">
      Three
    </div>

    <div class="nav-item  nav-item-four">
      Four
    </div>

  </div>

</div>


<div class="nav-container">

  <div class="nav">

    <div class="nav-item nav-item-one">
      One
    </div>

    <div class="nav-item  nav-item-two">
      Two
    </div>

    <three></three>

    <div class="nav-item  nav-item-four">
      Four
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: When I run your plnkr, they both look the same to me. I don't understand what's the problem here.

Comment: The first block is One, Two, Three, Four the second is Three, One, Two,  Four. The order on the Three element is isn't working

Comment: It appears you have you change/updated your original posted plnkr?...as it works and the 3rd is 3rd in both `nav-container`'s. This is exactly why the original code, as a working code snippet, should be posted within the question, so its initial code base is preserved. Any future users will now not be able to understand the difference between what you asked and what you got, very bad indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when angular renders your component, it wraps its inner view with an element called `three`. When you inspect your DOM, you'll see it. To fix it, you have to give order to `three` in your css file (either `style.css` or component css file) like following

in `style.css`

```
.nav-item-three, three{
    order: 3;
}
```

or component css file

```
three {
    order: 3;
}
```